# Linq and Entity Framework: Find first X datarows with same status

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following items in my database:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

1            1
2            1
3            1
4            2
5            2
6            3
7            2
8            2
9            1
```

I need a list of first 2 same status items:

Expected result loop 1:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

1            1
2            1
```

Expected result loop 2:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

3            1
```

Expected result loop 3:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

4            2
5            2
```

Expected result loop 4:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

6            3
```

Expected result loop 5:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

7            2
8            2
```

Expected result loop 6:

```
id           status      changeDate     userId      ....

9            1
```

After each loop the found results will be deleted.

How can I get the top 2 datarows where status is unique or with other words I want to find first x results with duplicated status?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "result loop 1"...

Comment: I'm doing loops. After every loop the results from the loop will be deleted from the database.

Comment: Hmm. I *think* I know what you mean, but it would be really helpful if you'd update the question with more details. (I assume you want to order by ID?) Why not just fetch the first two rows, and then discard the second one if it's got a different status? That's probably the simplest approach.

Comment: And what with rows 7, 8, 9, where status is lower that prev row status value? Should rows 7 and 8 appear in 5. loop? and 9 in last, 6 loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are deleting after each iteration, perhaps you could just use something like:

```
var nextTwo = yourTable.Take(2).ToArray() ;
var res = 
    nextTwo[0].status == nextTwo[1].status ? 
        nextTwo.Take(2) :
        nextTwo.Take(1);
```

After that, you can delete the row(s) matching 'res' and repeat.